# Require JS Compile React application

Tags: reactjs, gruntjs, require, webpack-4

I am working on React JS application. While building the code using grunt build I am getting the below error:

> ```
> Running "requirejs:compile" (requirejs) task
> Error: Cannot uglify file: C:/Dev/first-research/first-research-min.js.
> Skipping it. Error is:
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token: name (ClassicEditor)
>
> If the source uses ES2015 or later syntax, please pass "omptimize: 'none'" to r.js
> and use an ES2015+ compatible minifier after running r.js. The included
> UglifyJS only understands ES5 or earlier syntax.
> ```

- Calling webpack configuration from grunt to build and transpile from es6 to es5.

Attached are the Webpack, grunt, package.json and babel.rc file for ref

**Webpack file**

```js
const path = require('path'),
webpack = require('webpack'),
MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const { styles } = require( '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-utils' );

process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';

module.exports = {
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
          cacheGroups: {
            styles: {
              name: 'app',
              test: /\.css$/,
              chunks: 'all',
              enforce: true
            }
          }
        }
    },

    mode: 'development',

    entry: {
        'app': './src/app'
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json', '.scss', '.css'],
        modules: ['./node_modules']
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
        filename: '[name]-bundle.js',
        libraryTarget: 'amd'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\]icons[/\\][^/\\]+\.svg$/,
                use: [ 'raw-loader' ]
            },
            { // To process CKEditor CSS files.
                test: /ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\].+\.css/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'style-loader',
                        options: {
                          singleton: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: styles.getPostCssConfig( {
                            themeImporter: {
                                themePath: require.resolve('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-theme-lark')
                            },
                            minify: true
                        } )
                    }
                ]
            },
            // ESlint loader
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/, // include .js and .jsx files
                use: [
                    'eslint-loader'
                ],
                enforce: 'pre',
                exclude: /node_modules/ // exclude any and all files in the node_modules folder
            },
            // ES6 loader
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/, // exclude any and all files in the node_modules folder
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options:{
                        presets: ['env']
                    }
                }
            },
            // Style loader other than CK5 editor CSS files.
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: /ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\].+\.css/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    "css-loader"
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: /ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\].+\.scss/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    "css-loader",
                    "sass-loader"
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                exclude: /ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\]icons[/\\][^/\\]+\.svg$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'url-loader',
                    options: {
                        limit: 10000
                    }
                }]

            },
            // html loader
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'html-loader',
                    options: {
                        minimize: true,
                    }
                }]
            },
            {
                loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
                // Exclude `js` files to keep the "css" loader working as it injects
                // its runtime that would otherwise be processed through the "file" loader.
                // Also exclude `html` and `json` extensions so they get processed
                // by webpack's internal loaders.
                exclude: [
                    /\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/,
                    /\.html$/,
                    /\.json$/,
                    /ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\]icons[/\\][^/\\]+\.svg$/,
                    /ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\].+\.css/,
                    /(node_modules)/,
                    /\.css$/
                ],
                options: {
                  name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '[name]-bundle.css',
        }),
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({ options: {} }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
            }
        }),
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[\/\\]locale$/, /en-gb/)
        // new CKEditorWebpackPlugin( {
        //     language: 'pl'
        // })
    ],

    externals: [
        /^user-profile/, //OK
        /^settings\/settings/, //OK
        /^am-permissions\/permission/, //OK
        /^logger\/log/, //OK
        /^am-permissions/, //OK
        /^am-address/, //OK
        /^am-alerter/, //OK
        /^amfx-blotter-grid\//, //OK
        /^amfx-blotter-grid-components\//, //OK
        /^amfx-blotter-filters\//, //OK
        /^amfx-react-components\//, //OK
        /^menu\//, //OK
        'react', //OK
        'react-dom', //OK
        'prop-types', //OK
        /^jquery$/, //OK:
        /^underscore$/, //OK:
        /^lodash$/,
        /^q$/, //OK:
        /^d3$/, //OK:
        /^text/, //OK:
        /^d3-utils\//, //OK:
        /^bootstrap\//, //OK:
        /^moment$/, //OK:
        /^am-modal\//, //OK
        /^xhr-client\//, //OK
        /^q\//, //OK
        /^whatwg-fetch\//, //OK
        'immutable', //OK
        /^amfx-tab\//, //OK
        /^fx-blotter\//, //OK
        /^zap-tab-comms\//, //OK
        /^trade-operations\// //OK
    ],

    devtool: 'source-map',

    resolveLoader: {
        alias: {
            'css/css': 'style-loader'
        }
    }
};
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "first-research",
  "version": "0.1.18",
  "description": "first-research: Built using the Zambezi Platform",
  "main": "dist/react-your-component-name.min.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://stash.dts.fm.rbsgrp.net/scm/amfirstresearch/first-research.git"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --progress --watch --config ./config/webpack.dev.js",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-utils": "^10.0.3",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-theme-lark": "^11.0.0",
    "babel": "^6.1.18",
    "babel-core": "^6.14.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^6.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^15.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.13.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.14.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015-node5": "^1.2.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "babel-preset-react-hmre": "^1.1.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.6.1",
    "cross-env": "^1.0.8",
    "css": "^1.0.7",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "eslint": "^3.7.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^1.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^2.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.1.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "grunt": "^1.0.3",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "^1.1.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-requirejs": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-webpack": "^3.0.2",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^15.1.1",
    "jest-static-stubs": "^0.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.1",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.3.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^15.3.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^4.16.5",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0",
    "zambezi-contrib-build": "^2.1.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-adapter-ckfinder": "^10.0.2",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-autoformat": "^10.0.2",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles": "^10.0.2",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-block-quote": "^10.0.2",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^11.0.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-webpack-plugin": "^6.0.3",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-easy-image": "^10.0.2",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic": "^11.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials": "^10.1.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-heading": "^10.0.2",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image": "^10.2.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-link": "^10.0.3",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-list": "^11.0.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph": "^10.0.2",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react": "^1.0.0-beta.1",
    "@zambezi/sdk": "^5.19.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.4",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "^15.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.1",
    "react-modal": "^3.5.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-tabs": "^2.2.2"
  },
  "_zambezi": {
    "runtimeDependencies": [
      "am-address",
      "am-alerter",
      "am-permissions",
      "react",
      "react-dom",
      "css",
      "lodash",
      "prop-types"
    ]
  },
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^.+\\.(png|jpg|gif)$": "jest-static-stubs/$1",
      "^.+\\.(eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "identity-obj-proxy",
      "^.+\\.(css|less)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    }
  }
}
```

**Grunt file**

```js
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        build: {
            options: {
                optimize: 'none',
                include: ['first-research'],
                plugins: {
                    'css/css': '../node_modules/css/css',
                    'settings/settings': 'empty:',
                    "am-permissions/permission": "empty:",
                    "user-profile/user-profile": "empty:",
                    "logger/log": "empty:"
                }
            }
        },

        webpack: {
            dev: require('./config/webpack.dev.js'),
            prod: require('./config/webpack.prod.js')
        },

        watch: {
            files: ['src/**/*.js'],
            tasks: ['webpack:dev', 'build']
        }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-webpack');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('zambezi-contrib-build');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['webpack:dev', 'build']);
    grunt.registerTask('ci-build', ['webpack:prod', 'build']);
};
```

**babel.rc**

```json
{
  "presets": [
      "stage-0",
      "react",
      "es2015-node5"
  ],
  "plugins": [
      "transform-class-properties"
  ],
  "sourceMaps": true
}
```

Comment: Check this thread https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2972. Looks like you are using ES6 syntax but you don't have configuration set to handle the syntax

Comment: Use webpack insead of Grunt.

Comment: Yes, I am using webpack underline command to grunt. Attached the same in problem now. Also, image is just describing error not code etc. Its just extra information.